# My top-down shooter in pygame has varying speed missiles based on distance away from target, and I don't want that.

Tags: python, pygame

In my top-down shooter, the speed of my missiles vary depending on how far the mouseclick is away from the character. I don't want that. If there is no way of fixing my code, what would be the correct way of tackling this?
here is my missile class:

```
class Missile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, startx, starty, end_point):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.image = rot_center(pygame.image.load("missile.gif"), angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = startx, starty
        self.target = end_point
        self.start_point = startx, starty
        self.speed_constant = .05
        self.target_hit = False


    def update(self):
#the following few lines appear to be what my problem is
        speed = [self.speed_constant*(self.target[0] - self.start_point[0]),self.speed_constant*(self.target[1] - self.start_point[1])]
        self.rect.move_ip(speed)
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > self.area.width or self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > self.area.height:
            self.kill()
```

Comment: speed in your function s dependant on the distance between start_point and end_point(target) , what is the move_ip() attribute of rect? also, any reason why you don't want to use speed_constant attribute missile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide your speed vector by its magnitude to normalize the speed.
Your speed variable is defined as:
`speed=(x,y)`

You can change it to

`speed=(x/m,y/m)` where `m=sqrt(x^2+y^2)`

which would give you a constant speed no matter how far your target is. If the tip of blue vectors represent your target and the missile is located at origin. The green vectors represent normalized speed vector.

[image]